# Failed to connect: 0 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to send push notification to IOS users and every time i have this error: Failed to connect: 0 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

```
 $deviceToken = 'f672c26cbfb279e45c1b66d0ddb738d8043c785d5bb8dd20a72d52ae88d4a604';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';
$APNSCert = './IOS_PEM_File/my.pem';

    $PassPhrase = "1234"; 
// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Hello';
$auth = base64_encode("usr:123");
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$Options = array
                    (
                        'http' => array
                                    (
                                        'proxy' => 'tcp://10.0.8.23:8081',
                                        'request_fulluri' => true,
                                        'header' => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth"
                                    )
                    );

    $streamContext = stream_context_create($Options);
    stream_context_set_default($Options);
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $APNSCert);
    stream_context_set_option ($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $PassPhrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL; 

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
{   
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}
else
{   
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

}

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

i was trying to send using proxy server but it returns this error.

Comment: Did you find a solution?